# Calculation of coordinates in 3d with the 3dstructuralanalysis library

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, coordinates

The tikz library `structuralanalysis` provides the `point`command.

```
%------------------------------------------------
%       point
%------------------------------------------------
%           \point{name}{x-coordiante}{y-coordiante}
%           

\newcommandx{\point}[3]{
\node[coordinate][
    shift={(#2*\scalingParameter,
            #3*\scalingParameter)}](#1){};
}
```

So using this package I can define points by:

```
\point{a}{0}{0};
\point{b}{2}{3};
```

and by (using also the `calc` package):

```
\point{c}{$(a)+(b)$};
```

I would like to use the last line of code also in 3d using the `3dstructuralanalysis` library. This library provides the `dpoint` command for points in 3d.

```
%------------------------------------------------
%       3dpoint
%------------------------------------------------
%           \point{name}{x-coordiante}{y-coordiante}{z-coordiante};
%

\newcommandx{\dpoint}[4]{
   \node[coordinate][
        shift={(#2*\DscalingParameter,
                #3*\DscalingParameter,
                #4*\DscalingParameter)}](#1){};
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\DshowPointParameter}{1}}{
      \draw (#2*\DscalingParameter,
             #3*\DscalingParameter,
             #4*\DscalingParameter) node [above,red]{#1};
  }{}
}
```

So using this package I can define points by:

```
\dpoint{a}{0}{0}{0};
\dpoint{b}{2}{3}{4};
```

but not by

```
\dpoint{c}{$(a)+(b)$};
```

So the question is, is there a way to achieve this calculation of coordinates in 3d?

Comment: `\coordinate (c) at ($(a)+(b)$);`?

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. For me this solves the problem of using relative lengths.

Comment: @HenriMenke An answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, `\point` and `\dpoint` just create ordinary TikZ nodes.  Thus you can apply all the arithmetics from the `calc` library to these directly.  For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{3dstructuralanalysis}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \dpoint{a}{1}{1}{1};
  \dpoint{b}{2}{3}{4};
  \coordinate (c) at ($(a)+(b)$);
  \foreach \p in {a,b,c}
    \node at (\p) {\p};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Remains a bit the question: what is the benefit of introducing `\point` and `\dpoint`...